# Troubles with my Makefile

Tags: makefile

I downloaded [this](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/u3-ocaml/make/Makefile.ocaml) `Makefile` and I'm having a hard time understanding how it works.

I am programming in `Ocaml` and for some module, I implemented an `interface` (.mli). Strangely, even when I add the `.mli` file before the corresponding `.ml` file, the Makefile seems to skip it; so I'm getting the error

```
could not find the X.cmi for the module X.
```

Worse, I added some file without the required `.mli` and strangely again the Makefile automatically added them to the list of sources.
I'm saying **strangely** but perhaps its perfectly normal to Makefiles expert.

I'm not an expert when it comes to Makefile, can anyone help me understanding how this Makefile works?

The compilation works fine, when I replace the line

```
$(EXEC): $(OBJS) 
$(CAMLC) $(CUSTOM) -o $(EXEC) $(LIBS) $(OBJS)
```

With

```
$(EXEC): $(SOURCES) 
$(CAMLC) $(CUSTOM) -o $(EXEC) $(LIBS) $(SOURCES)
```

and add the required .mli

Comment: This may take a few iterations. What happens when you `make X.cmi`?

Comment: X.cmi doesn't exist at that moment, when I compile X.ml separatly with ocamlc, and make, the compilation is successful. X.cmi is the result of `ocamlc -c X.mli`

Comment: Exactly; when you `make X.cmi`, you are telling Make to build `X.cmi`. Make sees that `X.cmi` does not exist, so it looks for a rule to build it, sees that `X.mli` is present, and runs `ocamlc -c X.mli`. (That's what *should* happen.)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
# Makefile

PRG =

# Fichiers dans l'ordre
ML =
MLI = 

CMO=${ML:.ml=.cmo}
CMX=${ML:.ml=.cmx}
CMI=${ML:.mli=.cmi}

OCAMLFLAGS = -I
OCAMLLD = -ccopt -L.
OCAMLOPT = ocamlopt.opt
OCAMLC = ocamlc.opt
OCAMLDEP = ocamldep

${PRG}: ${OCAMLOPT} ${OCAMLFLAGS} ${OCAMLLD} -o $@ ${CMX}   
    make clean

.SUFFIXES: .ml .mli .cmo .cmx .cmi

.ml.cmx: 
    ${OCAMLOPT} ${OCAMLFLAGS} ${OCAMLLD} -c $<

.ml.cmo: 
    ${OCAMLC} -c $<

.mli.cmi: 
    ${OCAMLC} -c $<

clean:
    rm -f *~ *.o *.cm? *mli

fullclean: clean
    rm -f .depend ${PRG}

depend: .depend
.depend: ${ML} ${MLI}
    rm -f .depend
    ${OCAMLDEP} ${ML} ${MLI} > .depend

include .depend
```

You'll have to setup PRG, ML, MLI, FLAGS, LD. :)

Comment: I'll try your solution and report back, merci! ;)